# How to change advanced search frontend URL in magento2

Tags: magento2, plugin, advanced-search

I want to change frontend URL

> www.example.com/catalogsearch/advanced

to

> www.example.com/testurl

in magento2.

Also, How can I use the advanced search on any CMS page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Magento rewrites to change urls.
Go to `Admin Panel -> Marketing -> SEO & Search -> URL Rewrites` .

Answer (score -1):

You can change the frontend URL from the xml

Path: `app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/etc/routes.xml`

Like below:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="catalogsearch" frontName="testurl">
            <module name="VendorName_CatalogSearch" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```